# Not able to archive my app onto the New Build System on Latest Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode13

I am using Xcode 12.5.1, using native iOS to build my app. When I switch to New Build System I can run my app on my iPhone but I get error when I archive to make a production build.
Error:

```
Showing Recent Messages
duplicate output file '/Users/shashi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{project_name}-fqroszphviylkoamlhyrgcdwnfyc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/{project_name}/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/{project_name}.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftdoc' on task: Ditto /Users/shashi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{project_name}-fqroszphviylkoamlhyrgcdwnfyc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/{project_name}/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/{project_name}.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftdoc /Users/shashi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{project_name}-fqroszphviylkoamlhyrgcdwnfyc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/{project_name}/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/{project_name}.build/Release-iphoneos/{project_name}.build/Objects-normal/arm64/{project_name}.swiftdoc
```

I have tried to find duplicate files in Copy Bundle Resources but it's impossible cause I have lots of xibs files.

I am not able to upgrade to Xcode 13 cause of this issue.

Comment: Hey Matt! I followed the exact steps you mentioned. The errors persist.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?